# Netbeans shows error for unix system call "getcontext"

Tags: c++, c, netbeans

I'm currently implementing a threading library in linux (my OS is ubuntu natty). I'm using netbeans to do the project. I have to include the header `ucontext.h`, and have to call the unix system calls `getcontext()`, `setcontext()`, `makecontext()` and `swapcontext()`. The header is included fine and I'm able to use its structures like `ucontext_t`. But when I make a call to `getcontext()` or any of those functions, netbeans highlights them showing error

```
 unable to resolve identifier getcontext
```

However I was able to build and run the project. But I want to eliminate this error that is annoying, because it would be difficult for me to debug the code later on. Is there any way to make netbeans identify these system calls?
Thank you very much.

Comment: What is you netbeans version?

Comment: FYI, those are not actually system calls; they are C library routines.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem sounds similar to the problem discussed [on this blog](http://soledadpenades.com/2009/11/25/netbeans-unable-to-resolve-identifier-std-error/). Is Netbeans finding the include directories?

Comment: I restarted netbeans and it was fixed.. Don't know where it came from and where it went!